# Change kubernetes (kubeadm) logging away from /var/log/messages

Tags: logging, kubernetes

we have a kubernetes cluster running on Centos 7. However all logging is going to /var/log/messages which is making centos system logs hard to read. Is there a way I can tell kubeadm/kubernetes to log to /var/log/kubernetes rather?

We are already sending our application (pod) logs to a mountpoint. We need to move the stderr logs of kubernetes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However all logging is going to /var/log/messages which is making centos system logs hard to read. Is there a way I can tell kubeadm/kubernetes to log to /var/log/kubernetes rather?

No, not exactly, but you can reconfigure Docker to log in a different way.

This might depend on the Docker version you're running but in my CentOS 7 VM (a couple of weeks old) i'm running Docker version `1.13.1`, installed via `yum`.

When looking through the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/admin/logging/overview/) for version `1.13` and the latest [stable](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) version of Docker they say more or less the same thing:

> If you do not specify a logging driver, the default is json-file.

The version of Docker i installed via `yum` had the following line in an environment file (`/etc/sysconfig/docker`) that is loaded when starting Docker:

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false'
```

As you can see the logging driver are configured as `journald`, that should be the reason you're seeing logs from your containers in `/var/log/messages`. You can check which logging drive are configured with:

```
docker info | grep 'Logging Driver'
```

The logging driver decides where all of the logs, in Docker meaning `stderr` and `stdout` from containers are sent. Docker supports a couple of different [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers), if you choose to configure e.g. `json-file` which might be the best choice if you want to relocate the logging from an OS perspective ("changing" the log path). Every Docker container will have it's own log written to `/var/log/pods/<ID>/<NAME>/<LOGFILE>`, actually the log files are symlinks back to `/var/lib/docker/containers/<ID>/<ID>-json.log`.

If you do configure `json-file` then remove the `--log-driver=journald` flag and instead configure this in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, mentioned in the docs. With `json-file` you can configure things like log rotation and log file sizes, please consult the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#options) for more options.

When configuring via the `daemon.json` file this becomes a global setting, you can always override the logging driver used for a specific container with `docker run ... --log-driver`.

These logging changes applies for everything running within Docker, to move logging for e.g. `kubelet` which runs alongside Docker on your host you can look at the configurable [options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options). Default the `kubelet` `stderr` logs are logged via `journald` and ends up in `/var/log/messages`, to change this behavior can add the `--log-dir` options and point to another location.

In the end of the day i think it's good to give log shipping a thought and investigate the other logging drivers if they might fit into your environment.

Comment: I followed your hints, thanks, and marked you question as the answer, however I still have small things being written in the messages: Aug 12 03:25:49 kube-dev-master0 kubelet: W0812 03:25:49.673951    xxx container_manager_linux.go:792] CPUAccounting not enabled for pid: xxxx
Aug 12 03:25:49 kube-dev-master0 kubelet: W0812 03:25:49.673961    xxxx container_manager_linux.go:795] MemoryAccounting not enabled for pid: xxxx. Is there a way to move these as well?

Comment: @warhansen, i edited my answer and added a section regarding the kubelet logging. Hopefully this helps you with the last bit!